# Bytes Per 'Interval' in Windows XP Task Manager

Tags: windows, task-manager

In Windows XP, one of the columns for the network tab in task manager that I can add is Bytes Per Interval.  So what amount of time in seconds is a 'Microsoft Interval', 1.2?

I see there is 'Update Speed', but that is just Low, Normal, High .. Also totally useless ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the View tab in the Update Speed submenu and hover over the 4 different speeds you will get an explanation of what the intervals are in the status bar at bottom of the window.

- High = 2 updates / second
- Normal = 1 update / 2 seconds
- Low = 1 update / 4 seconds
- Paused = well, you can figure that out...

Comment: Happy 10K day! (And now, I type this to satisfy the 15 character minimum... joy...)

Comment: Happy 10k day Shawn!!

Comment: You guys are silly :-)  You're welcome for pushing you over squillman, but thanks for the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The interval duration depends on the Update Speed setting in the View Menu.

- High = Updates every 0.5 seconds
- Normal = Updates every second
- Low = Updates every 4 seconds

You can find this and more in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, you guys don't agree on what the Normal Interval is, but maybe that is because the Technet link is for Win 2000 ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at it on my XP box and the literal verbiage is "Updates the display every 2 seconds"

Comment: The default behaviour is 1 second and the update speed menu indicates this is "Normal" but changing it appears to be buggy.  If you change it from the default then Normal sets it to 2 seconds as squillman points out. To reset it back to 1 second you have to do some registry hacking it appears. This is news to me but you learn something new every day.